# Formula to concatenate values together

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I currently have this formula where it collects from 2 columns, in this example `CB` and `CC`, and concatenates them into column `CD`. 
The formula should round to 2 decimal if the first column is less than five, and 0 decimal if the first column is 5 or greater.

Here is the formula I put together to do that:

```
=IFERROR(IF(CB32 < 5,CONCATENATE(ROUND(CB32,2),"-",ROUND(CC32,2),"%"),CONCATENATE(ROUND(CB32,0),"-",ROUND(CC32,0),"%")),"")
```

Now I need to make sure that if either column `CB` or `CC` is empty, it doesn't pass back `0-0%` as it does with the `IFERROR` added still. Why is this?

Here is how I thought about doing it but doesn't seem to work correctly:

```
=IFERROR(IF(OR(OR(CB32 < 5, CB32<>"", CC32<>"")),CONCATENATE(ROUND(CB32,2),"-",ROUND(CC32,2),"%"),CONCATENATE(ROUND(CB32,0),"-",ROUND(CC32,0),"%")),"")
```

Comment: This sounds more like a SUM operation than a CONCATENATE. In any event, try `=ROUND(--(CB32&CC32), 2 * ((--CB32)<5))` . Showing sample data together with expected results would have made this question much clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to test from the start if the cells are empties :

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND(CB32="", CC32=""),"",IF(CB32 < 5,CONCATENATE(ROUND(CB32,2),"-",ROUND(CC32,2),"%"),CONCATENATE(ROUND(CB32,0),"-",ROUND(CC32,0),"%"))),"")
```

Comment: Can you please expand in your answer why IFERROR in my formula will pass back 0-0% for empty columns and *BLANK* in other formula areas with the same scenario?

Comment: @Brad : `0-0%` isn't an error, you'll have an error only if your values can't be rounded (ie strings) or are errors.

Comment: Correct, however with the formula I had, with both columns CB and CC being empty, my formula would give me either a 0-0%, or nothing at all. Same scenario, but different formula answer in different rows. Why is this? Sorry if my previous comment was a bit unclear.

Comment: @Brad : Mkay, clearer indeed. Wild guess would be the value of `CB32`, because Round(0 of empty probably wouldn't throw an error, but Round(2 of empty cells might. Does it seems to fit? (BTW, you had a useless `OR()` around the other one)

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up! (: I'm just trying to grab onto as much knowledge as I can. Hope you understand!

Comment: @Brad : Np! ;) Glad I could help! And I don't know if you tried Jeeped 's proposition but it's neat!